# Create a Multi Sheet Excel and send it as ByteArrayInputStream for downloading

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have created an excel file using Apache POI library, Excel is having Multiple Sheets.
The code is working fine but the only problem is that I'm creating a file in current directory(project directory). Is there any way to build an excel in memory and pass the byte for downloading it instead of creating an external file ("ExcelDownload.xlsx")

> ServiceClass below

```
public class GenericExcelService {

  public static <T> void writeToExcelInMultiSheets(final String fileName, final String sheetName, final List<T> data) {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
      File file = new File(fileName);
      Sheet sheet = null;
      if (file.exists()) {
        workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
      } else {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
      }
      sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      workbook.write(fos);
      fos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        if (workbook != null) {
          workbook.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Inside Last IOException");
      }
    }
    }
  }
```

> Controller below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void writeToExcelInMultiSheets(){

    File currDir = new File(".");
    String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
    String fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + "ExcelDownloadDemo.xlsx";

    GenericExcelService.writeToExcelInMultiSheets(fileLocation, "Person Details", persons);
    GenericExcelService.writeToExcelInMultiSheets(fileLocation, "User Details", users);
    GenericExcelService.writeToExcelInMultiSheets(fileLocation, "Contact Details", contacts);   
}
```

I tried implementing the same code for a non-void method to return a downloadable excel file using `ByteArrayInputStream` but I was unable to return more than one value. Kindly assist
Made the following changes in `controller` & `service` but didn't work.

> change in `service` is below, instead of void return type is ByteArrayInputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//in place of
//fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
//workbook.write(fos);

workBook.write(outputStream);

return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream);
```

> change in controller return type to `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>`
>   and below

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis;
bis = GenericExcelService.writeToExcelInMultiSheets(fileLocation, "Contact Details", contacts);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Details.xlsx");

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What about writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead to a `FileOutputStream`? Then get the `byte[]` array from that stream and construct a `ByteArrayInputStream` from that?

Comment: @AxelRichter i tried with `ByteArrayOutputStream ` but it will get the value of last sheet of the workbook only.